# How to remove an array element from Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm new to MEAN stack. I'm trying to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472858/removing-an-element-from-array-in-mongodb) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959099/how-to-remove-array-element-in-mongodb). I'm using `$pull`. But they ain't working maybe because my structure in mongodb is different from theirs. So let me first show you that:

[image]

`downvoters` is an string array that contains userids who downvoted that particular article. Lets say the person on `downvoters[2]` i.e `53et853rf` later upvoted this article.Then his userid should be removed from downvoters list. Here is my code:

**api.js**

```
router.put('/update-upvotes', (req, res) => {
  let articleData = req.body;
  ...
  Article.update(
    {articleid: '5p4aqbryi'},
    { $pull: { downvoters: '53et853rf' } }
  );
  Article.findOneAndUpdate(
    {articleid: '5p4aqbryi'},
    {upvotes: articleData.upvotes, upvoters: articleData.upvoters}, useFindAndModify=false,
    (error, user) => {
      if(error) {
        ...
      }
      else {
        ...
      }
    })
   })
```

But that id is not deleted. There's no error or warning on console. Please correct me.

And here is the **schema**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const articleSchema = new Schema({
  articleid: String,
  title: String,
  content: String,
  date: String,
  contributor: String,
  upvotes: Number,
  upvoters: [],
  downvotes: Number,
  downvoters: []
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('article', articleSchema, 'articles');
```

PS: Let `articleId` and `downvoter id` be hardcoded now. I'll make them dynamic later.

Comment: add a `.catch(e=>console.log(e))` at the end for error logging.

Comment: Added.  But still no error or warning. It is just not doing my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `upvoters` and `downvoters` are `String` arrays so your Mongoose schema should look like below:

```
const articleSchema = new Schema({
    articleid: String,
    title: String,
    content: String,
    date: String,
    contributor: String,
    upvotes: Number,
    upvoters: [String],
    downvotes: Number,
    downvoters: [String]
});
```

You should also keep in mind that `update()` is an asynchronous operation which needs to be `awaited` or handled as Promise so:

```
let opResult = await Article.update(
    {articleid: '5p4aqbryi'},
    { $pull: { downvoters: '53et853rf' } }
);
```

or

```
Article.update(
        { articleid: '5p4aqbryi' },
        { $pull: { downvoters: '53et853rf' } }
    ).then(opResult => console.log(opResult));
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. But the first solution is giving this error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`. And the second one had no change at all, nothing happened.

Comment: You need to mark your function as async, like: `async () => { await Article.update(...) }` . Besides that I've tested your example and it works so please make sure that you're running your query on the collection where your data resides. Try to make sure that `Article.findOne({ articleId: '5p4aqbryi' })` returns the document you're trying to modify.

Comment: Yes. everything else is working perfectly in the code. `Article.findOneAndUpdate()` is also working . But I'm afraid I didn't understand "You need to mark your function as async" very well.

Comment: You can read this: http://thecodebarbarian.com/80-20-guide-to-async-await-in-node.js.html

Comment: Sir I'm so sorry. My bad. Your second solution is working. But It should be `{ articleid: articleId }`. Just now i see the edit also.

Comment: And please make sure that you're "awaiting" the execution of first function. Otherwise `update` and `findOneAndUpdate` may interfere with each other. If you can't use awaits run `findOneAndUpdate` in a callback of `update()`

Comment: @Tanzeel yep, sorry for that typo :)

Comment: No problem Sir. :-). thanks for this. Hope this will pas unit test cases as well. Or else I'll come back to you. ;-)

Comment: @Tanzeel lesson learned - `update` returns `Promise` which needs to be `await`-ed or the continuation should be run as `.then()` otherwise the operation won't get executed

Comment: I'll always remember this. :-). By the way. You an see this: http://fast-depths-77615.herokuapp.com/options. this is what I'm making.